# when i trying to login by registered user it showing this error

Tags: mean-stack

This is the error i am facing i am working on a mini project which is better explaining with this youtube link - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zzs2CzovhEI&list=PLUVqY59GNZQP8SlrFewicML2dSAUxBfAS

i found error on 4th lecture

Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at LocalStorage.setItem (C:\Users\RadheKrishna\Desktop\RPROJECT\Rproject\node_modules\node-localstorage\LocalStorage.js:176:27)
    at C:\Users\RadheKrishna\Desktop\RPROJECT\Rproject\routes\index.js:49:31
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\RadheKrishna\Desktop\RPROJECT\Rproject\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\RadheKrishna\Desktop\RPROJECT\Rproject\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\RadheKrishna\Desktop\RPROJECT\Rproject\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\RadheKrishna\Desktop\RPROJECT\Rproject\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\RadheKrishna\Desktop\RPROJECT\Rproject\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\RadheKrishna\Desktop\RPROJECT\Rproject\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\RadheKrishna\Desktop\RPROJECT\Rproject\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\RadheKrishna\Desktop\RPROJECT\Rproject\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (C:\Users\RadheKrishna\Desktop\RPROJECT\Rproject\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\RadheKrishna\Desktop\RPROJECT\Rproject\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\RadheKrishna\Desktop\RPROJECT\Rproject\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\Users\RadheKrishna\Desktop\RPROJECT\Rproject\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\RadheKrishna\Desktop\RPROJECT\Rproject\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\RadheKrishna\Desktop\RPROJECT\Rproject\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)

Answer (score 0):

This means that .

> toString()

method doesn't work. Can you please be more elaborate and paste code as well.